# How to authenticate when using cloudfoundry apis in a spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I want to use cloudfoundry apis (https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/) in a simple spring boot app.

I'm following a documentation for implmenting a java client for it. (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-client.html)

My pom.xml ->

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-client-lib -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudfoundry-operations</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The Controller and Application file is exactly the same as mentioned in the sample simple spring boot startup kit. (https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/).

When *using a standalone class (as mentioned in the cloudfoundry docs) it works*,  but when using the same code in a spring boot app, it gives me -

```
{
    "timestamp": 1510245582167,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
    "path": "/hello"
}
```

I noticed in the logs that when I have the `cloudfoundry-client-lib` dependency added, A filter chain is formed..

```
2017-11-09 11:34:38.086  INFO 8648 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], 
[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@288ca5f0, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2ba5aa7a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4207609e, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2c7a8af2,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@21c815e4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@22e5f96e,
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5b22d8a1, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4068102e, 
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@67b100fe, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@704641e3,
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@7efd28bd]
```

How to deal with the authentication when using cloudfoundry lib or how to deal with bypassing the filter chain security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Solution: CF Java Client v2 has a different API from v1, so you won't find `CloudCredentials` in v2. See the v2 `README` for examples of constructing a new client and providing credentials: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryclient-dopplerclient-uaaclient-builders Again, use only the v2 libraries and don't use any v1 libraries in the same app.

---

I'm not sure exactly where that error is coming from, but you are mixing different major versions of the CF Java client in the same app. That's not likely to work very well. Refer to the project page for the [CF Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) and use only `2.x.x` versions of all the `org.cloudfoundry` dependencies. All of the `org.cloudfoundry` dependencies should also be on the same versions.

So replace:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-operations</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-reactor</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-operations</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried with that as well. The problem occurs when I have the `cloudfoundry-client-lib` dependency! As soon as its in, the filter chain gets triggered when the server starts and when hitting the end point, the authentication fails.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `cloudfoundry-client-lib` with the other CF Java client dependencies? You don't need that library.

Comment: Even I thought its not requiredm but `CloudCredentials` is available only in `cloudfoundry-client-lib`, None of the other dependencies are able to resolve at compile time.

Comment: CF Java Client v2 has a different API from v1, so you won't find `CloudCredentials` in v2. See the v2 README for examples of constructing a new client and providing credentials: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client#cloudfoundryclient-dopplerclient-uaaclient-builders. Again, use only the v2 libraries and don't use any v1 libraries in the same app.

Comment: That works.. curious question, is there any way we can make Restful calls to the cloudfoundry apis through spring boot? I mean, if I need to get the exact results of /v2/apps/<guid>/stats call, using this approach, I need to construct the whole json on my own, Is there any simpler way to fetch that info ?

Comment: If you just need to use a few simple API calls, you can just use `RestTemplate` to make REST calls to the CF API, but you'd need to configure a `RestTemplate` with OAuth2 credentials. That might look something like this (completely untested and likely incomplete) snippet: https://gist.github.com/scottfrederick/d23b4e6639d286936ce10a3be098bd93.